# How to check if Json response is empty in Angular 4?

Tags: json, angular

How can I check if a JSON response is empty?

```
GetEmpName(){
  this.Emp.empservicecall()
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.name = response[0].name
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it is having values or not by

```
if(response && response.length > 0)
```

in order to fix compile time error, you need to define a type for the response, make it as any

```
 this.Emp.empservicecall()
    .subscribe((response : any) => {
```

Comment: it is giving compile time error at line response.length

Comment: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: is it necessary to give type for response .